# Sort Documentation tags based on Favorite Tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, documentation

Would it be possible to have documentation tags float to the top of the list based on our SO favourites?

Comment: I've updated the title; I couldn't get the image of tags floating like clouds around the Documentation section out of my head. Feel free to revert if that makes less sense :).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Sort away Mike, sort away! Whatever makes the post more readable.